# Variadic function wrapper considering references and const

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates

I created a small function wrapper example. I want to make the wrapper consider whether or not the function called is using (const) references, meaning the output will be 4/5 and not 4/4, but I don't want to enforce reference usage if the wrapped function does not use them.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

struct a {
  static void run(int cref) {
    cref = 5;
  };
};

struct b {
  static void run(int &cref) {
    cref = 5;
  };
};

template <class FTor>
struct foo {
    template <class ... Args>
    static void wrapper(Args ... args) {
      FTor::run(args ...);
    }
};


int main()
{
    int bar = 4;
    foo<a>::wrapper(bar);
    std::cout << bar;

    foo<b>::wrapper(bar);
    std::cout << bar;
}
```

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/ref

Comment: add an overload accepting a const reference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about just using perfect forwarding?

```
template <class FTor>
struct foo {
    template <class ... Args>
    static void wrapper(Args && ... args) {
      FTor::run(std::forward<Args>(args) ...);
    }
};
```

That way, whatever ref-qualification the parameter has on input gets passed along to the inner function.

Comment: Not sure I follow, how will `wrapper()` be deducing it's argument types not based on what you feed it but based on the wrapped function signature as the OP I believe wanted.

Comment: @SkepticalEmpiricist From my interpretation of the question, I think he just wants the example he provided to work. I don't think he actually cares if `wrapper` could deduce the type or not.

Comment: Edited my answer to reflect this fact.

Comment: [live sample](https://wandbox.org/permlink/7qpuBsLwYgaBXo6d), and sample [without perfect forwarding](https://wandbox.org/permlink/fNiY2MyNiPB2K73u).

Comment: @MarekR Yeah you could also pass in `std::ref` to get around copying the function arguments, though you don't get a compile error if you forget to do that. With perfect forwarding, however you get a compile error if you pass in the wrong cv-ref qualification.

Answer (score 1):

This is an attempt to answer what is possibly a misinterpretation of mine regarding the OP's request, as simple perfect forwarding solves the scenario described without resorting to the wrapped function arguments' types deduction.

Original answer: At least for the restricted use case such as you're presenting, you can use a small type trait struct to infer the type of *single argument* being passed to `wrapper()` from the type of argument of the functor:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

struct a {
  static void run(int cref) {
    cref = 5;
  };
};

struct b {
  static void run(int &cref) {
    cref = 5;
  };
};

template <typename>
struct ArgType;

template <typename R, typename A>
struct ArgType<R(A)>
{ using type = A; };

template <class FTor>
struct foo {
    static void wrapper(typename ArgType<decltype(FTor::run)>::type args) {
      FTor::run(args);
    }
};

int main()
{
    int bar = 4;
    foo<a>::wrapper(bar);
    std::cout << bar;

    foo<b>::wrapper(bar);
    std::cout << bar;
}
```

Output:

```
45
```

Note this won't support *perfect forwarding* from within the wrapper, as `wrapper()` here is not itself part of a *type deducing context` -- as opposed to your snippet, that deduces but not based on what you want it to deduce. I'll hopefully find the time to add a generalized solution for *variadic* function template such as in your snippet, *perfect forwarding* included.

Comment: But that's a single arg, you can't turn it into a pack.

Comment: @bipll Roget that, apologies. Editing to rectify.

Comment: just for interest what is the difference in comparison to the deleted && solution

Comment: @dgrat Sorry I must have missed it before being deleted. The essence in this somewhat incomplete answer, is to define your `wrapper()` method based on the signature of the specific `run()` itself, so it would take the same types, and so your reference remains a reference all the way through.

Comment: This also won't work if the function is overloaded or a function template.

Comment: @ I think you may be right, thanks for the lookout! Hoping to get back to this soon enough.